# The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I've been learning flutter for 2 months. I'm trying to develop a wallpaper app. I created a model and a function. But right now I can only download 1 wallpaper. How can I make this a list? I get this error when I make a list.

This is url.

```
  String url =
      'https://images.hdqwalls.com/download/the-witcher-season-2-2022-5k-u1-1080x1920.jpg';
```

the list i want to use

```
  List<String> url = [
    'https://images.hdqwalls.com/download/the-witcher-season-2-2022-5k-u1-1080x1920.jpg',
    'https://images.hdqwalls.com/download/the-witcher-season-2-2022-5k-u1-1080x1920.jpg',
  ];
```

and function

```
  void saveimage() async {
    await GallerySaver.saveImage(url, albumName: album_name);
  }
```

and clicking this button provides download

```
 ElevatedButton DownloadButton(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        minimumSize: Size(40, 40),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade600.withOpacity(0.1),
      ),
      child: Icon(Icons.download, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7)),
      onPressed: () {
        saveimage();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
            content: Text('Wallpaper downloaded!'),
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: '',
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUuVh.png)

The packages I use are

- gallery_saver: ^2.3.2
- async_wallpaper: ^2.0.1

I want to use it in gridview

```
GridView.builder(
        itemCount: url.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 9 / 16,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              child: FullScreenWidget(
                child: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
                  Image.network(url, fit: BoxFit.cover),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    void saveimage() async {
       for(int i = 0; i <= url.length; i++) {
            await GallerySaver.saveImage(url[I], albumName: album_name);
         }
      }
```

Above code will resolve your error

Comment: The error is gone but when I want to load a different wallpaper from the list it always downloads the first wallpaper.

Comment: this time it downloads all images in 1 click :(

Answer (score 0):

Let consider you want to download image when you click on the card then code will be like as following.

```
void saveimage(String imageUrl) async {
    await GallerySaver.saveImage(imageUrl, albumName: album_name);
  }

GridView.builder(
  itemCount: url.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  childAspectRatio: 9 / 16,
  ),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  return GestureDetector(
  onTap: (){
    await saveimage(url[index]);
  },
    child: Card(
    child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
    child: FullScreenWidget(
    child: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
    Image.network(url, fit: BoxFit.cover),]),),);),
  ),)
```